# How did this character survive in the season 2 finale of Heroes?

Tags: heroes

In the season 2 finale of Heroes, [Powerless](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1054832/?ref_=ttep_ep11)

> Nathan

is shot in the chest a couple of times.  Then, in the season 3 premiere, [The Second Coming](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1185907/?ref_=ttep_ep1),

> he comes back to life after being pronounced dead, and appearing to be dead for several minutes after that at least.

How is this possible?  The initial explanation is that Linderman saved him, but we learn later that this is definitely not the case.

Comment: Good question. Peter was close enough to Linderman to potentially absorb his healing power. It is possible he unconsciously used it in the hospital as Nathan lay dying. No evidence of that though.

Comment: @JackBNimble I had not thought of that.  He almost definitely had Linderman's power at the time.  Do we even know if that power was able to resurrect the dead?

Comment: I don't think so. We do know that Claire and Adam's blood can bring people back from the dead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[NBC released an app](http://www.nbc.com/heroes-reborn/app) a little before ["Heroes Reborn"](http://www.nbc.com/heroes-reborn) aired that included a video summary of Peter's history which includes what NBC must consider significant moments. One of these is from "The Second Coming" in which Peter is alone in the emergency room with a deceased Nathan and he holds Nathan and kisses his forehead. Seconds later Nathan sits up very much alive. It's interesting that NBC considers that a significant *Peter* moment rather that a *Nathan* moment.

It is evident in the episode that Peter doesn't know he has absorbed healing powers and can use the ability or he would have tried to heal Nathan at the site of the incident or in the ride over in the ambulance but, with no-one else in proximity and having been exposed to Daniel Linderman (healing powers), Jason Greer (healing touch) and getting pretty close to Future-Peter in the same episode in all his multi-power awesomeness including rapid cell regeneration from Claire Bennet, Present-Peter's picked up a little awesomeness of his own and, in an emotional flood of love and loss, brings his brother back from the dead.

**Yatta!**